# MongoDB Comparing Dates Inconsistently Working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a chunk of code in mongoDB / javascript that is sometimes working, but other  times not. When I go to compare dates, this code works:

```
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    User.aggregate([ 
        { $match: { emplyID: Number(req.params.emplyID) } },
        { $match: { "dateReq": { $gte: new Date(year, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(year+1, 0, 1) } } }
 ], function (err, pto) {
console.log(pto.length)
 }
```

Console log results = 2

However, this does not work:

```
let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    User.aggregate([ 
        { $match: { emplyID: Number(req.params.emplyID) } },
        { $match: { "dateReq": { $gte: new Date(year - 1, 0, 1), $lt: 
new Date(year, 0, 1) } } }
 ], function (err, pto) {
console.log(pto.length)
 }
```

The console log is always equal to 0.

In the current DB, these objects exist:

DateReq : 3/9/19,
DateReq : 3/8/19,
DateReq : 10/20/18,
DateReq: 11/15/18

The first function is supposed to count the number of entries that exist between 2018 and 2019, and does it correctly, finding two items. The second function is supposed to count the number of entries that exist between 2017 and 2018, but even though the data exists, it can not be found. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Those are not proper dates, they seem to be arbitrary date strings. Don't expect arbitrary date strings to be handled as you would expect them to.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the DateReq strings? I apologize for being inaccurate, I was being lazy as they are actually stored like this: "dateReq" : ISODate("2019-03-09T15:16:32.405Z"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, and it had nothing to do with the MongoDB date comparison. Instead, I had failed to provide a req.params.emplyID like the first request had. I actually needed to use req.payload.emplyID, and everything worked correctly after that.